# bitcoin-cli remove an account

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts

How i can remove an account created on my server?

```
coincoin@localhost:~# bitcoin-cli listaccounts 
{
  "": 0.00000000,
  "first": 0.00000000,
  "perso": 0.00000000
}
```

I juste want to delete "first" account

Comment: I don't think there's currently a way. I looked at all of the account-related rpc calls, and `setaccount` can change the account of an address. However, that doesn't delete the account once all of them are gone.

Comment: @NickODell ah! At least, the things are clear! Thank you for the information

Comment: Also the `accounts` feature is deprecated https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/1287